# Karma/Jasmine passing objects to custom directive and access it

Tags: angularjs, compilation, jasmine, karma-runner, directive

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    describe('TestButton', function () {
    var controller, element, util;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
        module('template');
        module('TestUtil');

        inject(function (TestUtilService) {
            util = TestUtilService;

            var testFunc = function foo(){
                return 5;
            };

            // Passing the defined function to the custom directive and call it via 
            // controller.clickButton (it will be fired there)
            // function=\' + testFunc + '" passing the function as string also not working
            element = '<custom-button id="btn1" label="Click Me" function="testFunc"></custom-button>';

            element = util.compileElement(element);
            controller = util.getController(element, 'customButton');
        });
    });

    it('should be resolved', function () {
        expect(element.html()).toContain('input');
    });

    it('should be set', function () {
        expect(element.find('input').val()).toBe('Click Me');
    });

    it('should be set', function () {
        expect(element.find('input').attr('id')).toContain('button_btn1_');
    });

    it('should fire the passed function', function () {
        //controller.clickButton() should log 5 or something, but its not working at all
        //controller itself is working perfect (I have access to the whole directive-scope)
    });
});
```

TestUtilService :

```
this.compileElement = function (element) {
    var el = vm.$compile(element)(vm.$scope);
    vm.$scope.$digest();
    return el;
};


this.getController = function (element, directiveName) {
    return element.controller(directiveName);
}
```

How can I pass an object to the directive, compile it and access it. I also have problems with passing arrays or something. How does that work in Karma/Jasmine??

Would be wonderful, if someone could give me some tips.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've experienced, you can't do this directly through the directive alone; however, if you want to add the functionality of the function (or the object), you can shim it in through whichever isolate scope object you're using in the test.

However, **you should not be asserting on its existence.**  A test that fires your custom function **will pass** if the function is excluded:

```
scope.testFunc = function(){console.log(1)};
element = '<custom-button id="btn1" label="Click Me"></custom-button>';
```

This is because the scope *already* has the function it cares about.

One thing to do in this scenario is to set up a condition in which the function *is* passed in and is presumed to be working; effectively, you'd be injecting the function in for testing purposes.  May be worth mocking at this point to ensure that it fires in the way you expect it to, but assertions beyond that are not going to be valid.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define your passing object at the created scope in Karma/Jasmine like so:

```
scope.testFunc = function(){console.log(1)};
element = '<custom-button id="btn1" label="Click Me" function="testFunc"></custom-button>';
```

Comment: At best, this leads to a red herring.  You're not *actually* compiling the object into the directive; you're supplying it directly to it.  Any assertions on its existence would be false assertions, since you can remove the expression for it from the directive *and it will still pass*.